# Python FastApi Model validation failure when using docker containers

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I'm running into a very stranger issue when using a python FastAPI app with Redis DB. Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out why scenario 2(see below) is failing.
Below I have described the scenarios and some general thougths.

Here are scenarios

### Scenario 1 (working)

- Redis-db runs on docker container using localhost:6379
- Fastapi runs locally on machine without container
- created simple JSONModel that references a BaseModel/EmbeddedJsonModel
- when running app, i can see in logs that fast-api is connected to redis
- if i post to fastapi app, redis db is populated without issue

### Scenario 2 (non-working)

- Redis-db runs on docker container using localhost:6379
- Fastapi app is running in docker container on same container netowkr as redis-db
- created simple JSONModel that references a BaseModel/EmbeddedJsonModel
- when i run docker-compose up...both containers start and i see that fast api app is connected to redis db
- if i post to fastapi app, i get exception suggesting there is no DB-connection
  NOTE: if i convert my simple model to HashModel and remove all references to BaseModel/EmbeddedJsonModel, there is no problem

### FastApi code

```py
import logging
from typing import Optional, Any

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Response, status
from redis_om import Migrator, NotFoundError, get_redis_connection, HashModel, EmbeddedJsonModel, Field, JsonModel
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra, ValidationError, validator

app = FastAPI(title="FastAPI_Test_App")
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.warning("CONNECTING TO REDIS_HOST: redis-db")
redis_con = get_redis_connection(host="redis-db", decode_responses=True)

class CustomerBase(EmbeddedJsonModel, BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    age: int

#CustomerBase.Meta.database = redis_con
log.warning(f"CustomerBase DB connection data: {CustomerBase.Meta.database}") # default database uses localhost
class Customer(JsonModel):
    base: CustomerBase

Customer.Meta.database = redis_con  # type: ignore
log.warning(f"Customer DB connection data: {Customer.Meta.database}") # this shows redis-db which is CORRECT
@app.get('/customers')
async def all():
    customer_pks = Customer.all_pks()
    return [format(pk) for pk in customer_pks]

def format(pk: str):
    c = Customer.get(pk)
    return {
        'id': c.pk,
        'name': f"{c.first_name} {c.last_name}",
        'age': c.age
    }
@app.post('/customers')
async def create(customer_base: CustomerBase):
    c = Customer(base=customer_base)
    #c.Meta.database = redis_con
    return c.save()
    #return customer.save() # THIS WORKS ALONE...NO OTHER LINES NEED IN THIS FUNCTION

if __name__ == "__main__":  # pragma: no cover
    log.warning("Running customer app")

    # Create a RediSearch index (required for all processes that operate with Tasks)
    Migrator().run()

    # TODO Move uvicorn to extras_require (if not used in prod)?
    import uvicorn

    # TODO Add cache in "on event startup"
    uvicorn.run("main_REPRODUCE_FAILURE:app", reload=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, log_level="debug")
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install iputils-ping
RUN groupadd -g 1000 appuser && \
    useradd -rm -s /bin/bash -d /home/appuser -u 1000 -g 1000 appuser


WORKDIR /home/appuser
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN pip install -vvv -e .


EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]
CMD ["python main_REPRODUCE_FAILURE.py"]
```

### Docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis-db:
    image: redislabs/rejson:latest
    restart: always
    command: redis-server --loglevel debug
    volumes:
      - fastapi-redis-test:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - fastapi-redis-test
    environment:
      fastapi-redis-test_ENV: development
  fastapi-redis-test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #command: python main.py
    image: fastapi-redis-test
    depends_on:
      - redis-db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - fastapi-redis-test
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis-db
    volumes:
      - .:/home/appuser
volumes:
  fastapi-redis-test:
    driver: local

networks:
  fastapi-redis-test:
```

#### exception when running post using localhost:5000/docs

```
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | CONNECT TO REDIS_HOST: redis-db
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | CustomerBase DB connection data: Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | Customer DB connection data: Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=redis-db,port=6379,db=0>>>
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | CONNECT TO REDIS_HOST: redis-db
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | CustomerBase DB connection data: Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | Customer DB connection data: Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=redis-db,port=6379,db=0>>>
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | INFO:     Started server process [14]
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | INFO:     Application startup complete.
fastapi_redis-redis-db-1            | 1:M 07 Oct 2022 18:08:40.685 - DB 0: 27 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
fastapi_redis-redis-db-1            | 1:M 07 Oct 2022 18:08:40.685 . 1 clients connected (0 replicas), 838736 bytes in use
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | INFO:     172.21.0.1:58606 - "POST /customers HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 611, in connect
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     return do()
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 612, in <lambda>
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 677, in _connect
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     raise err
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 665, in _connect
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     sock.connect(socket_address)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | 
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | 
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     raise exc
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     raise exc
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     raise e
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 680, in __call__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 275, in handle
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     response = await func(request)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 221, in app
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     solved_result = await solve_dependencies(
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 561, in solve_dependencies
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     ) = await request_body_to_args(  # body_params checked above
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 696, in request_body_to_args
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     v_, errors_ = field.validate(value, values, loc=loc)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 884, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.validate
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 1101, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._validate_singleton
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 1148, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._apply_validators
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "pydantic/class_validators.py", line 318, in pydantic.class_validators._generic_validator_basic.lambda13
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "pydantic/main.py", line 711, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.validate
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis_om/model/model.py", line 1469, in __init__
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     if not has_redis_json(self.db()):
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis_om/checks.py", line 17, in has_redis_json
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     command_exists = check_for_command(conn, "json.set")
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis_om/checks.py", line 9, in check_for_command
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     cmd_info = conn.execute_command("command", "info", cmd)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1235, in execute_command
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1387, in get_connection
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     connection.connect()
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 617, in connect
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
fastapi_redis-fastapi-redis-test-1  | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

#### Some Troubleshooting Thoughts:

During the redis connection, i can see that fastapi is correctly using the container name: redis-db
What i find interesting is that the stacktrace suggests that during the post, it tries to connect to localhost instead, which I know is bad b/c that means app is trying to connect to my local machine instead of redis container.
Upon seeing this error, one thing i tried was to add the redis-db connection within Meta-class of the CustomerBase and Customer classes.  In doing so, I no longer got the exception.  Instead i got an HTTP 422 - unprocessable entity failure.  I assume this is just b/c by doing some i've broken the normal model.
So that leaves me to wonder...why is app using localhost instead of redis-db during post ? OR...is there some other strange problem.  I'm really thinking there is something else going on b/c as mentioned earlier...this **failing setup** works just fine when app is not on a container but redis is on a container.

i'm not sure if this is the actual problem...but that is what i'm led to believe based on staack trace.
I'm open to all suggestions :)

any help would be appeciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here seems to be with the `redis_om` library. Looking at the very last line in your traceback, we see `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.`, i.e., it's still trying to connect to redis on `localhost`, even though it may seem like you've configured it to connect to `redis-db`.

Looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python/blob/main/docs/connections.md), there are two ways to configure the library, either by setting the `REDIS_OM_URL` environment variable (which you would do by setting `REDIS_OM_URL=redis://redis-db:6379` in your `docker-compose.yml` file), or by adding an inner class to your model:

```py
class Customer(JsonModel):
    base: CustomerBase

    class Meta:
        database = redis_con
```

I would guess that trying to configure the connection after class declaration, as you're doing with `Customer.Meta.database = redis_con` doesn't work.

Comment: What's interesting about this...is that I've tried this.  When I add the meta-class to either the CustomerBase or customer models, the exception goes away.  BUT...thenn i'm stuck on HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity.
Any ideas how to get around that issue ?
I will test out the ENV you mentioned.  THANKS!!!

Comment: What error traceback do you get with the inner class? (Just an FYI: a metaclass in python is something else, this is an inner class called `Meta`, a quite confusing name).

Comment: 422 means that you're not sending the content that the endpoint expects; look at the body to get information about the actual missing data.

Comment: Thanks for the help @M.O.
Using the ENV resolved the primary issue.  The seperate 422 seems to have been related to my docker compose networks.  After removing them, issue is now resolved.